# Defining Collections in drl file

Tags: java, rules, drools

I'm going to do some ruling stuff with drools.
This is the first time I use this tool and, for functional requirements, i've thought a need to define a weights data-structure in a drl document.

I have to use the "java-like" syntax (i don't even know if there are others types of syntaxes at this moment).

Is there any way to write down programmatically any kind of java collection in a drl file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MVEL or Java syntax in the Drools DRL rules.

You can also use any Java collection. If you want to make a new collection you need to do it in the rule RHS part and if you want to use it in the rules you need to use insert for that.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

Rule "Example Rule"
  when
    # Your condition
  then
    Collection collection = new ArrayList();
    # add what ever you want into the collection
    insert( collection );
end
```

Comment: Does it insert the whole collection as a single fact, or every object in the collection as a new fact?

Comment: The collection as a single fact.